# Why does 9.0 + 4.53 + 4.53 yield 9.05 when β = 10 and p = 3?

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm reading this paragraph in *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*:

> (6) [image]
>
> (Suppose the triangle is very flat; that is, a ≈ b + c. Then s ≈ a,
>   and the term (s - a) in formula (6) subtracts two nearby numbers, one
>   of which may have rounding error. For example, if a = 9.0, b = c =
>   4.53, the correct value of s is 9.03 and A is 2.342.... Even though the computed value of s (9.05) is in error by only 2 ulps, the
>   computed value of A is 3.04, an error of 70 ulps.

from: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#1403

I wonder why `(a+b+c)/2` is equal to 9.05, where `a = 9.0`, and `b = c = 4.53`?

I suppose a hardware it may concern will calculate `a+b` first, which results `13.53`, rounded to `13.5`. Then `c` will be added to `13.5`, giving us `18.03`, which is eventually rounded to `18.0`. Finally, `18.0` is divided by `2`. This yields `9.00`, and is given to variable `s`. It is assumed that this hardware has at least one guard digit.

So where is wrong?

Comment: `s = (a + b + c) / 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they did `b + c = 9.06` first, then added `a + 9.06 = 18.06`, rounded that to `18.1` they'd get to `9.05`.

I guess this detail is not that important, the point is that with only three significant digits,

- you'll end with `9.00` or `9.05`, but not with the correct `9.03` (even though that number could be represented)
- every additional operation you do introduces more inaccuracy, so that the end result can be off by far more than just the three digit limitation (`3.04` vs `2.342...`, which does not get even the first digit right)